# Using Powershell to Do Action Every Time a Specific Outlook Email is Received

Tags: powershell

I receive a lot of emails from people to copy a file from one file location to another. I would like my Powershell program to automate this process that whenever I receive an email with a specific subject line, my program completes the action above and sends an email to the sender that this has been completed. My copy and paste code, testing the path, and sending an email by themselves work. Running the code in its entirety doesn't give me an error but also doesn't do anything. I have left comments in the code below where I think the problems are (can't be sure though)

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)
$emails = $inbox.Items | Where-Object {$_.subject -match ‘COPY FILE’}  #I think might be wrong
if ($_.subject -match 'COPY FILE') #I think might be wrong
{
    Copy-Item -Path ($oldLocation + $fileName) -Destination $newLocation
    if (Test-Path -Path ($newLocation + $fileName))
    {
        $mail = $outlook.CreateItem(0)
        $mail.To = $sender
        $mail.Subject = "Completed"
        $mail.Body = "File has been successfully moved"
        $mail.Send()
    }
    else
    {
        $mail = $outlook.CreateItem(0)
        $mail.To = $sender
        $mail.Subject = "Failed"
        $mail.Body = "File does not exist in $newLocation"
        $mail.Send()
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity wouldn't this create a fairly large security flaw especially since you most likely have admin rights to files others do not? i.e. if they could figure out the name of a file they shouldn't have access to all they would have to do is send you an email and they could get access to it without your review? Why have the process of asking you first if you don't need to verify anything?

Comment: QQ --- Why not just do this using Exchange rules? Why do this in PowerShell when Outlook Rule or Outlook built-in VBA feature set is more direct? You can have the eMail msg and any attachments auto-save to a given target.

Comment: @Elfie Because the sender can only send 1 data entry at a time that each get appended in a single file if anything exists in their designated file path (which file will be removed when permission is given). Copying the file over to the new location is where we have a second script that automatically manipulates the file once a file exists in there which we then have to send back to the sender. I hope that answers your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your If statement is referring to `$_` but there's no surrounding loop or pipeline.

Just a suggestion but maybe:

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)
$emails = $inbox.Items | Where-Object {$_.subject -match ‘COPY FILE’}  #I think might be wrong
$Emails |
ForEach-Object{
    if ($_.subject -match 'COPY FILE') #I think might be wrong
    {
        Copy-Item -Path ($oldLocation + $fileName) -Destination $newLocation
        if (Test-Path -Path ($newLocation + $fileName))
        {
            $mail = $outlook.CreateItem(0)
            $mail.To = $sender
            $mail.Subject = "Completed"
            $mail.Body = "File has been successfully moved"
            $mail.Send()
        }
        else
        {
            $mail = $outlook.CreateItem(0)
            $mail.To = $sender
            $mail.Subject = "Failed"
            $mail.Body = "File does not exist in $newLocation"
            $mail.Send()
        }
    }
}
```

Also; I don't know if they are defined elsewhere but I don't see any definition for `$oldlocation`, `$filename`, or `$newlocation`.  I'd have thought you need to parse those out of the subject or body of the message.

`$Sender`, might need to be `$_.Sender` in this example.

Comment: I apologize. I should have provided examples for those variables to show that I already have that information. This worked! Thank you so much!